# JavaScript change input type="text" to type="file"

Tags: javascript

So I have a code that is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fundx() {
    var input = document.getElementById("id");
    var input2 = input.cloneNode(false);
    if (document.getElementById("butid").value == 'Upload') {
        input2.type = 'text';
        input.parentNode.replaceChild(input2, input);
        document.getElementById("butid").value = 'URL';
    } else {
        input2.type = 'file';
        input.parentNode.replaceChild(input2, input);
        document.getElementById("butid").value = 'Upload';
    }
}
</script>
<input id="id" type="text" name="id"  value="Upload" />
<input type="button" id="butid" value="Upload" onclick="fundx()" />
```

It is supposed to change the text field to a file upload field and vise versa.

The current code isn't working. Any ideas of what I should do to fix this?

Comment: Works fine for me, what browser are you testing this in?

Comment: where do the extra characters `";` at the end of line 16 come from?

Comment: not a best solution, but works. what errors do you have in cosole?

Comment: @devnull69: Sorry, it was part of the code of the php section, I'll remove them.
@ putvande , deadulya : I've tried it in w3 schools "try it editor". It doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the cloning. You cannot change the type of an existing element, you can only set the type for a new element (once).

Try this

```
function fundx() {
    var input = document.getElementById("id");
    var input2 = document.createElement('input');
    input2.id = input.id;
    input2.name = input.name;
    input2.value = input.value;
    if (document.getElementById("butid").value == 'Upload') {
        input2.type = 'text';
        input.parentNode.replaceChild(input2, input);
        document.getElementById("butid").value = 'URL';
    } else {
        input2.type = 'file';
        input.parentNode.replaceChild(input2, input);
        document.getElementById("butid").value = 'Upload';
    }
}
```

Working example on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jufokese/1)